# Trying to get date format contact form 7 post data

Tags: php, wordpress

```
 $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
 $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
 $date= $posted_data['date-120'];
```

`$date` returns standard format is **Ymd**, how get format **d.m.Y** ?

Comment: Have you tried converting with `strtotime()`? Something like `$date = date( 'd.m.Y', strtotime( $posted_data['date-120'] ) );`

CF7 Also has format parameters in the shortocde `[date date-120 date-format:dd/mm/yy]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [date_format](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp):

```
$date = date_format($posted_data['date-120'],"d.m.Y");
```

Comment: @WilliamNash what do you exactly have in $posted_data['date-120']? Can you var_dump it?

Comment: $posted_data['date-120'] this field cf7 [date date-120]

Comment: @WilliamNash and what's the value?

Comment: @WilliamNash you did not answer my question for the second time. What's the value of $posted_data['date-120']?